# How do I get a program to recognize a duplicate key in a dictionary when prompted to add a new key value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

In my code I'm prompting a user to add a new key in a dictionary, brave_roster. What I'm having trouble with is getting the program to not execute when an existing key-value is input by the user.

```
def main():
# initial roster
    brave_roster = {
        "Austin Riley": "AB: 615, R: 90, H: 168, HR: 38, AVG: 0.273",
        "Ronald Acuna": "AB: 467, R: 71, H: 124, HR: 15, AVG: 0.266",
  }
    
    
    print("\t ***  Braves Stats!  ***\n")
    print("Welcome to My Braves Stats! What can I do for you?\n")
    print("  1. Search for a player")
    print("  2. Add a new player")
    print("  3. Remove a player")
    
    
    name = brave_roster
    stats = brave_roster
    choice = input("Please type your choice number:")
    if (choice == "1"):
        name = input("Enter the name of the player you want to lookup:\n")
        new_roster = lookup_player(brave_roster, name)
       
    elif (choice == "2"):
       name = input("Enter the name of the player you want to add:\n")
       stats = input("Please add the player's stats:\n")
       new_play = add_player_to_dict(brave_roster,name,stats)
    else: 
        (choice == "3")
        name = input("Enter the name of the player you want to remove:\n")
        delete_in_dict(brave_roster,name)


#my code:

    
def add_player_to_dict(brave_roster,name,stats):
   if name not in brave_roster:
        brave_roster[name] = stats
        brave_roster.update([(name, stats)])
        print("Here's", ["name"],"'s stats:\n")
    for name, stats in brave_roster.items():
        print(name, ':', stats)
        return brave_roster[name]
    else:
     if name in brave_roster.items():
        if name in brave_roster:
          brave_roster[name]= [brave_roster[name]]
        print("That player is already on our roster.")
        
    return brave_roster[name]
  
main ()
```

For example:

```
Welcome to My Braves Stats! What can I do for you?

  1. Search for a player
  2. Add a new player
  3. Remove a player
Please type your choice number:2
Enter the name of the player you want to add:
Austin Riley 
Please add the player's stats:
```

when prompted to add a new player and the user inputs a name already in the dictionary it should execute "That player is already on our roster." The program should not ask for the player's stats.

Comment: It would help if you posted a sample transcript of exactly what the program displays and what you entered, and explain how the result output isn't what you wanted.

Comment: I can't run this code, because it has indentation errors.  Obviously the code runs for you, so you must have made a slight cut-and-paste error when you posted the code.  Please review your post and specifically check the indentation in the `add_player_to_dict()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the right idea, but there's a lot of code you don't need. This should do it:

```
def add_player_to_dict(brave_roster,name,stats):
    if name not in brave_roster:
        brave_roster[name] = stats
        print(f"Here's {name}'s stats:\n{stats}")
    else:
        print("That player is already on our roster.")
    return brave_roster
```

I've removed the `for` loop as that would print the stats for all players, not just the new player. The dictionary `update` method seems to be redundant so I've removed that as well. I've changed the print statement to use f-strings as they're more readable. The `else` section has been simplified.

Comment: I don't think this solves the OP's problem, because they want this line: `stats = input("Please add the player's stats:\n")` not to execute when the `name` is already there. Which isn't really possible only modifying `add_player_to_dict`; they'd have to either move the reading of the stats into `add_player_to_dict`, or move the check for the name already existing out to `main`, so it can be used to bypass reading in stats.